# Combine two domain objects to a view

Tags: design-patterns, database-design, architecture, domain-driven-design

How would you combine two domain models in application design?

I got a domain model called **Team**, that includes:
  - id
  - name
  - description

And I got a domain model called **TeamUser**, that includes:
  - userId
  - teamId
  - roleType

The API consumer want a view that contains:
  - id (id of the team)
  - name
  - roleType

So this is a combination of data from the **Team** and **TeamUser** domain models, because the view contains `roleType` (and maybe more later).

How would I model this? And in which layer will this happen (service, repository, controller)? Because there is a difference in my database design and the actual presentation view.

Answer (score 2):

> How would I model this?

You should create new DTO projection model for dedicated view that fits exactly its needs. That means something like - `TeamDto` with attributes - `id`  - `name` - `roleType`

> And in which layer will this happen (service, repository, controller)?

You will project result of your database query (querying only needed data) to DTO in your repository. If you do it in latter stage (service, controller), that most probably means that you read inefficiently data from DB (e.g. loading whole Team and TeamUser and than combining them together)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Jan Muncinsky said, you can explore [CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html), where you will be using two separate models, one for command and one for query, in that way your domain model won't be constrained by the constantly changing UI queries.